# How to implement a recycler view inside a viewpager2

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Basically, I want to add a recycler view inside a viewpager2 which will have 3 tabs that can be swiped left/right to switch tabs, and in each tab there will be present the recycler view which can be swiped vertically.
But every time I try to do that either viewpager2 is working (when the height of viewpager2 is set to match parent) or the vertically scrollable recycler view (when the viewpager2 height is set 0dp)
I am not getting any solutions from anywhere.(I am using kotlin for my app)
For reference take example of whatsapp which has both tablayout and recycler view I am looking for the same functionality.
Please help!!!

This is content_main.xml (it is the activity_main.xml file of my code)
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">




<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />






<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/recent" />

       

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/saved" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tools" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

`

And this is xml file of individual tabs fragment.recent.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".tabrecentFragment">

 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_status_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/status_item" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the kotlin file of the above xml tabrecentfragment.kt

```
    class tabrecentFragment : Fragment() {

private var binding: FragmentRecentBinding? = null
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recent, container, false)

}
```

This is all the code and the other two tabs will be empty for now.
Also the recycler view inside the recent fragment is not showing in the recent tab layout but showing inside the content_main.xml which is the main xml file that shows content inside it universally throughout the app.
Please give any solutions to this.

Comment: Please add what code you have done for achieving this, then you are more likely to get help.

Comment: Okay... I am adding the code

Comment: @mohit48 I've attached the code please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I see there are a lot of problem with your code lets fix them one by one.

In your activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="tablayout"/>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/recent" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/saved" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tools" />
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In your recent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".tabrecentFragment">

 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_status_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/status_item" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Create a ViewPagerAdapter which returns Fragment

```
class MyFragmentAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    private val totalTabs: Int,
): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return totalTabs
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return //condition to return fragment based on position
    }
}
```

In your MainActivity, call that adapter

```
tablayout.adapter = MyFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager , tablayout.tabCount)
```

And then in your Recent fragment use recycler view using its adapter

Comment: I did what you suggested to me but  in

Comment: I've used tablayoutmediator earlier in mainactivity.kt and when i added the code you suggested to me it got a lot of error and also in getitem after return i added          return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                tabrecentFragment()
            }
            1 -> {
                tabsavedFragment()
            }
            2 -> {
                tabtoolsFragment()
            }
           3 -> {
               latestFragment()
           }
            else -> {
                tabrecentFragment()
            }    
        }

Comment: so what to do please help!!

Comment: What errors did you get?